# Jetpack Compose, Recomposition and recompositions scopes. How does it accually work?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I was experimenting with the recomposition for the past few days and I do not get some of it. Some scopes are getting recomposed and I do not know why.

Let me first present you with the code I am experimenting with:

**Entry point**

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
) {
    var counter1 by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "Surface")
    Column {
        Button(onClick = { counter1++ }) {
            LogCompositions("Jetpack", "ButtonScope1")
        }
        Component("text1", counter1)
    }
}
```

**Custom composables**

```
@Composable
fun Component(text: String, counter1: Int) {
    var counter2 by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "Component")
    Column {
        Button(onClick = { counter2++ }) {
            LogCompositions("Jetpack", "ButtonScope2")
        }
        CustomText(counter1.toString())
        CustomBlock {
            LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope1")
            CustomBlock {
                LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope2")
                // CustomFun(counter2.toString(), "text2")
                CustomBlock {
                    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope5")
                    CustomText(text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun CustomFun(text1: String, text2: String) {
    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomFun")
    CustomBlock {
        LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope3")
        CustomText(text1)
        CustomBlock {
            LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope4")
            CustomText(text2)
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun CustomText(text: String) {
    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomText $text")
    Text(text)
}

@Composable
fun CustomBlock(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlock")
    content()
}
```

[How it looks on after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGuVL.png)

Clicking on first button causes `counter1` to be changed and recomposition begins. Logs:

```
Compositions: Surface 1
Compositions: Component 1
Compositions: CustomText 1 1
Compositions: CustomBlockScope1 1
Compositions: CustomBlockScope2 1
Compositions: CustomBlockScope5 1
```

So we see that `Surface block scope` is getting recomposed together with its child `Component`. It makes sense because the `State` object is being read in there. Going into `Component`, `CustomText` child is getting recomposed as it reads the changed function parameter. And here starts the questions.

**Why do `CustomBlockScope1`, `CustomBlockScope2` and `CustomBlockScope5` are getting recomposed as well?**

**If 1 parameter passed to fun is a state and the other one is just some constant, will the recomposition happen even for the constant object?** (well not a state, but a read to a state)

**Then why do `CustomText(text)` is not getting called and recomposed but only the scopes?** (maybe because of string is stable and it can skip recomposition? but why then the scopes get recomposed?)

**Do scopes get evaluated from top to bottom or from the most inner one to the top?**

Lets change the function a little, uncomment the call to `CustomFun` and comment out the `CustomText(text)`. Lets see what happens:

```
Compositions: Surface 1
Compositions: Component 1
Compositions: CustomText 1 1
Compositions: CustomBlockScope1 1
Compositions: CustomBlockScope2 1
```

`CustomBlockScope5` is not recomposed right now, but the 2 other scopes are. If now comment out the `CustomFun` call it will not get called and only `Surface` `Component` and `CustomText` will recompose.

**Why call to the function which reads different `State` object triggers the recomposition of the outer scope?**

Lastly, lets check what happens when we click the second button and change the state of `counter2`. For this we uncomment the `CustomText(text)` and `CustomFun` calls, in `Component`.

```
Compositions: CustomBlockScope2 1
Compositions: CustomFun 1
Compositions: CustomBlockScope3 1
Compositions: CustomText 1 1
Compositions: CustomBlockScope4 1
Compositions: CustomBlockScope5 1
Compositions: CustomText text1 1
```

Scope surrounding the `CustomFun` together with `CustomFun` are getting recomposed. Inside `CustomFun` we have the same case as in `Component` so `CustomText` which reads the mutated state gets recomposed, and constant parameter only recomposes the scopes.
But when we go back to `Component` function we see that the `CustomBlockScope5` and `CustomText` are getting recomposed.
**Why does it happen?**
Wrapping "text1" inside `remember` block, stops `CustomText` from recomposing, but the `CustomBlockScope5` still gets recomposed.

```
Component(remember {"text1"}, counter1)
```

**Also, if recomposition is triggered by function call with different parameters then the whole function recomposes, and can skip inner recomposition scopes/function calls, but when the function gets recomposed by the read to `state` it can skip its own scope and only recompose scopes and call that reads the state?**

I think thats all of the questions I have for now. Ive read the [donut-hole skipping article](https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/donut-hole-skipping-in-jetpack-compose#recomposition-scope) from where I got the `LogCompositions` fun. I also read this [article](https://dev.to/zachklipp/scoped-recomposition-jetpack-compose-what-happens-when-state-changes-l78)

If you have any more docs/articles/blog posts please let me know. I would like to really understand the recomposition, but the amount of information I can find about the topic is limited :< If you know also some answers to my questions then I would be delighted to read and understand them all :D

Comment: I admit I am still trying to understand that myself. One of compose developers have done [a presentation about it on devoxx 2019](https://youtu.be/6BRlI5zfCCk), that I've found very useful. The same developper also has a [series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcgGtmZOsTwG6LqPut_BxX6w9DRr2unU6) about compose internals (I have not looked at them yet, however).

Comment: @amanin Thanks for the links, I will be sure to check them in the free time.

Answer (score 1):

**Why do CustomBlockScope1, CustomBlockScope2 and CustomBlockScope5 are getting recomposed as well?**

=> it is because the 'text:String' that is an input of Component has been captured in the lambda. If you comment CustomText(text) like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Component(text: String, counter1: Int) {
    var counter2 by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "Component")
    Column {
        Button(onClick = { counter2++ }) {
            Text(text = "counter2")
            LogCompositions("Jetpack", "ButtonScope2")
        }
        CustomText(counter1.toString())
        CustomBlock {
            LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope1")
            CustomBlock {
                LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope2")
                // CustomFun(counter2.toString(), "text2")
                CustomBlock {
                    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope5")
                    // CustomText(text) <------------------ Commented
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you will only get:

```
Compositions: Surface 1
Compositions: Component 1
Compositions: CustomText 1 1
```

Lets say that you really want this CustomText: then you may pull the lambda up:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Component(counter1: Int, customBlockContent : @Composable ()-> Unit) {
    var counter2 by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "Component")
    Column {
        Button(onClick = { counter2++ }) {
            Text(text = "counter2")
            LogCompositions("Jetpack", "ButtonScope2")
        }
        CustomText(counter1.toString())
        customBlockContent()
    }
}

Component(counter1){
    CustomBlock {
        LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope1")
        CustomBlock {
            LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope2")
            // CustomFun(counter2.toString(), "text2")
            CustomBlock {
                LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope5")
                CustomText("text1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

by doing so, a change in counter1 do not raise a recomposition of custom block which do not capture anything external to it

You get on click:

```
Compositions: Surface 1
Compositions: Component 1
Compositions: CustomText 1 1
```

**Then why do CustomText(text) is not getting called and recomposed but only the scopes?
(maybe because of string is stable and it can skip recomposition? but why then the scopes get recomposed?)**

=> Yes indeed: no parameter has changed, the function is skipped

**Do scopes get evaluated from top to bottom or from the most inner one to the top?**

=> outer to inner: from your root and each fun that could be skipped will be. (so there is a big advantage if you skip a whole part of your code using immutable inputs)

**Why call to the function which reads different State object triggers the recomposition of the outer scope?**

=> same as first one: you capture counter2 in the scope by calling CustomFun(counter2.toString(), "text2"). If you comment it, your lambda become pure again and so it will not be recomposed.

**Also, if recomposition is triggered by ... only recompose scopes and call that reads the state?**

=> This one is more tricky:

1. The scope for CustomBlockScope2 is invalidated as a read of counter2 happen with [CustomFun(counter2.toString(), "text2")] which lead to

- Compositions: CustomBlockScope2 1

2. The CustomFun is called with direct implication for:

- Compositions: CustomFun 1
- Compositions: CustomBlockScope3 1

3/4) THEN, the lambda

```kotlin
CustomBlock {
    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope4")
    CustomText(text2)
}
```

capture text2 BUT text2 has not changed.

a close thing happen for:

```kotlin
 CustomBlock {
    LogCompositions("Jetpack", "CustomBlockScope5")
    CustomText(text)
}
```

Both are triggered by their closure and if you comment CustomText(text2) or CustomText(text) you will skip the lambda and the associated log.

BUT there is a difference in CustomText behaviors and here, I am not sure of the reason why... Sorry

My guess (but just it) is that in an ideal world, they would not be recomposed but tracking their values as a closure happen is maybe too costly, or not done yet, or has side effects (like what happen if you keep a variable with the lambda that you call it later).

Keep in mind that the more pure lambda are, the more skipeable they will be. And that pulling lambda up could prevent recomposition of whole part.